# How do you get Google's indoor map view to automatically rotate?

Tags: google-maps

My code is currently responsive, but I am wondering how do I get the map to automatically rotate? Thanks.

Example: http://virali.se/photo/spin/embed/00c79439f35e4833d4b3c350f6af0043.html#embed

```
<style>
.google-maps {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%; // This is the aspect ratio
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.google-maps iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
</style>
 <div class="google-maps">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m0!3m2!1sen!2sca!4v1417361836017!6m8!1m7!1sD80WPU9LQ3oAAAALCpZfjw!2m2!1d45.71770335915593!2d11.47028447620278!3f17!4f0!5f1.4199149422479231" width="1700" height="550" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically rotate"?

Comment: See here: http://nap360.com/

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done when you embed the panorama via an iframe.

You'll need to create the panorama via the javascript-API and start an interval which increases the heading of the panorama:

```js
function initialize() {
  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
    {pano:'D80WPU9LQ3oAAAALCpZfjw',
     pov:{heading:0,pitch:0},
    disableDefaultUI:true}
  );
  panorama.setZoom(0);
  setInterval(function(){
    var pov=panorama.getPov();
    pov.heading=(pov.heading+.1)%360;
    panorama.setPov(pov);
  },10);  
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I dropped the entire code in LayerSlider and it just displayed the following and the rest cut off:  function initialize() {
  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
    {pano:'D80WPU9LQ3oAAAALCpZfjw',
     pov:{heading:0,pitch:0},
    disableD

Comment: I dropped the code in the SO-snippet-editor and when I hit the "Run code snippet button" above I see a rotating streetViewPanorama

Comment: Hm you're right.  The problem is I'm dropping it into a Wordpress plugin (LayerSlider) and I think I'm missing a crucial piece of code to get it to run.